# What is the source for Mikvah as it relates to Kedusha?

Tags: tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, mikvah-ritual-bath, kedusha-holiness

The Torah discusses using a Mikvah to allow oneself to be rid of ritual impurity (Tamei) to a state of purity (Tahor).

Nowadays, many people go to the Mikvah (e.g, erev shabbos) to obtain a higher state of Kedusha (holiness). Where do we see a source that the Mikvah has any bearing on Kedusha?

What I am looking for specifically is a source that details Mikvah as a source for Kedusha, not (just) Tahara.

Comment: Kohanim in the mikdash would tovel without being tameh - most famously the Kohen Gadol on YK, multiple times, without any chance to become tameh in between

Comment: Mesilas Yesharim says Tahara is a prerequisite for Kedusha.

Comment: @Shalom You should emphasize that Ramchal is only making that statement based on the explicit teaching from Rabbi Pinchas ben Yair concerning the path of Nevuah. See Yerushalmi Shekalim 3:3, Mishnah Sotah 9:15, Avodah Zarah 20b, Yerushalmi Shabbat 1:3, Sha’arei Kedusha, Part 2 4:10.

Comment: @AKA Nice point. KG aside, where do you find it by a KH?

Comment: @Shalom yes but it’s my understanding the Tahara in MY is a spiritual purity (there’s certainly nuance here) but the Torah idea of Mikvah is ritual purity.  Perhaps a source linking these ideas could help bridge the gap?

Comment: @AKA That’s a good point,  but is there any sources that outside of that context there’s any spiritual benefit? I can certainly see that as being a starting point.

Comment: While I haven't learned it inside shylas and teshuvas min hashamayim gives reasons why it's a good idea to still go to the mikvah daily even though tekanas Ezra was abolished

Comment: @Nahum See Yoma 3:3, אין אדם נכנס לעזרה לעבודה, אפילו טהור, עד שיטבול.

Comment: @Meir Ty. Nice. Same Mishnah as regarding KG. I see in tosefta that one opinion says it was for good reason—מקבילות בתוספתא יומא ג':ג'
רַבִּי יְהוּדָה אוֹמֵר: לֹא הָיְתָה טְבִילָה זוֹ אֶלָּא מִפְּנֵי הַצֹּרֶךְ: פְּעָמִים שֶׁטֻּמְאָה יְשָׁנָה בְיָדוֹ. מִתּוֹךְ שֶׁהוֹלֵךְ לִטְבֹּל, נִזְכָּר שֶׁהוּא טָמֵא, וְהוֹלֵךְ וּבָא לוֹ.

Comment: @Nahum Yes, and the other (Ben Zoma, Yoma 30a-b) says that it's based on a kal vachomer, but not that there's any tumah involved.

Comment: I like @AKA's source as they don't involve any change in status however one finds tevilah when becoming Jewish which doesn't involve removal of any technical tumah. Ditto for tevilas keilim. I think when the bnei aharon and leviyim were initially appointed there was a tevilah as part of the initiation process. These all involve an elevation in kedusha and a permanent change in status so not an exact analogy to the question however they are dunks that aren't for the removal of tumah.

Comment: The mikva purity of the body is only outside purity, a shadow for the Spiritual or the real. The water represents purity, it cannot make one holy as much the Circumcision in itself makes no difference. Even if you find such a ref will u accept it blindly?

Answer (score 1):

Kabbalah speaks about the significance of going to mikvah [before](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%A2%D7%A8_%D7%94%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%AA/%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%99_%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%AA#%D7%A2%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%9F_%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%98%D7%91%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%94) (and [on](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%A2%D7%A8_%D7%94%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%AA/%D7%93%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%99_%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%AA#%D7%98%D7%91%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%94_%D7%91%D7%A9%D7%97%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%AA)) shabbos. In [Pri Etz Chaim](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%99_%D7%A2%D7%A5_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A9%D7%A2%D7%A8_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%AA_%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A7_%D7%92) it's written that doing so removes the "weekday garments" of the soul and draws down the holiness of shabbos:

> צריך לעורר אותך קודם קבלת שבת בקריאת שמו"ת, ואח"כ בטבילה. ומצוה שמו"ת
> בזמנה יום ו' אחר חצות, שאז נפרד הקליפה מהקדושה... ואח"כ בכוונת טבילה,
> משפיעין הארת קדושת שבת, לזה אמר "יתפרדו כל פועלי און"... ומנהג מורי
> זלה"ה, לקרוא פרשת השבוע בכל ערב שבת... ואחר קריאת הפרשה, היה טובל בערב
> שבת, והיה אומר כי אחר שקרא הפרשה של שבת, כבר יש יכולת לקבל תוספות
> שבת... והיה אומר, כי תוספות שבת, הוא ניכר ונתגלה תיכף אחר הטבילה במצח
> אדם, אך עיקר הגלוי לא היה רק אחר חצי היום, ודווקא אם כבר טבל, והסיר
> בגדי חול של הנפש על ידי  הטבילה

As for going during the week, there are many sources in [chassidus](https://www.mikvah.info/media/Vetaval_Bemayim_Hebrew.pdf) and [nigleh](https://daat.org.il/shut/%D7%98%D7%91%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%AA-%D7%91%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%95%D7%94-%D7%9C%D7%92%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D/) for the idea of purifying oneself in the mikvah before serving Hashem, especially for one who is a [baal keri](https://shulchanaruchharav.com/halacha/chapter-8-tevilas-ezra-for-a-baal-ker/).

Comment: Is there any nigleh source that suggests purifying oneself not for keri? You make it sound like there is. Keri is a real halachic impurity, not just "extra kedusha"

Comment: Possibly duplicative of what @DoubleAA said, I am looking for sources that bring a reason for Mikvah *outside* of Keri. Keri is from the Torah, and the Mikvah therefore removes Tumah. Can you bring any sources specifically for Kedusha?

Comment: @DoubleAA The letter I linked to was about tevilah in general. I've updated the link to include some additional sources reflecting AKA's comment above, as well as Nahum's answer.